# notify-send rom IRC log

Tags: shell, irc, irssi

I'm trying to have my remote ssh session send me notifications locally when my nick is mentioned on IRC.

The following code pops a Notification window saying "IRC Message", but with no content, every time my nick is mentioned or I type something in IRC.

The only time it's actually showing content is when I do a "/me" action, so "*nick and content" show up under "IRC Message" along with a timestamp.  What am I doing wrong that it won't show regular messages?

```
ssh ircuser@server.net "tail -n 1 -q -f ~/irclogs/*/*.log|grep -i --line-buffered usernick"|while read line;do notify-send "IRC Message" "${line}";done
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It was a problem with the MATE notification center, it expected HTML format from notify-send and used the 
"<>" tags around the nick as tags. Made a work around

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'r looking on the right file logs..=P

Not sure, but you might try `stdbuf -o0 grep nickname` or unbuffer

Comment: log files are correct because it pops up when it catches the nick, just doesn't have anything in the ${line} ...   I don't know what stdbuf -o0 does but I tried it, same results

Comment: the presence of special char ('\r') crossed my mind..but forgot about the <>/html, good one!

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the MATE notification center, it expected HTML format from notify-send and used the "<>" tags around the nick as tags. Made a work around